# Mapping formats for small autonomous robots

Tags: mapping

I have some robot software I'm working on (Java on Android) which needs to store a pre-designed map of a playing field to be able to navigate around. The field's not got any fancy 3d structure, the map can be 2d.

I've been trying to find a good format to store the maps in.
I've looked into SVGs and DXFs, but neither one is really designed for the purpose.

Is there any file format specifically designed for small, geometric, robotics-oriented maps?

The field I'd be modelling is this one:
[image: FTC playing field]

Comment: How about some XML-file? Define nodes for geometric primitives and model the obstacles with them.

Comment: You could have a look at GDAL (http://www.gdal.org/), which has a comprehensive list of raster and vector-based standard map formats (http://www.gdal.org/ogr_formats.html). It has Java bindings, but I don't know if it can be built for Android.

Answer (score 2):

I really don't think the format matters, so I'd suggest you go for what's most convenient to you.  You might want something that can be displayed easily on screen, any bit map format will do.

You could even use a simple text file with occupied grid squares marked, a really simple example below:

```
1111111
1000001
1110001
1000001
1111111
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have specified that a geometric description format was desired.